# Identify YA horror novel that may have some fantasy aspects

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

I read a novel as a child that I believe was intended for a young adult audience (which I wasn't, and it therefore scared the pants off me). The details are fuzzy but I think it was written in the 70's as it was a newish paperback then. It was about a young girl who kept going down into this hole in a rocky cliff area behind her house (kinda like a well, with a ladder, but into a small natural cave area). She would go down and take food and play with her "friend" down there, another girl who was the same age. I just remember it being very scary, not sure if there were supernatural or fantastical forces or if it was just creepy. In the end, the reader finds out that the "friend" is actually not even alive and is just a corpse of someone (maybe her twin??) that died years ago. Eeewwww.... anyone able to identify that, please and thanks??

Comment: Probably not what you were looking for, but it reminds me of the movie Nell http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nell_(film), which also had a child with a dead twin she used to visit. Which is based upon a play from the 90's.